# HtmlUnit Encoding Exception

Tags: java, htmlunit

I try to login my university web-site with HtmlUnit(Version 2.12) but I have a problem relevant to encoding of the web site

code :

```
    try {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_9);
        WebClientOptions options = webClient.getOptions();
        options.setCssEnabled(false);
        options.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        options.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        options.setRedirectEnabled(true);
        options.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);   
        HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("http://www.oid.hacettepe.edu.tr/cgi-bin/menuindex.cgi");

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AnaSayfa.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AnaSayfa.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Exception :

```
java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: İSO-8859-9
```

I also try to change charset with this code :

```
WebRequest webRequest = new WebRequest(new URL("http://www.oid.hacettepe.edu.tr/cgi-bin/menuindex.cgi"));
webRequest.setCharset("utf-8");
HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage(webRequest);
```

but my problem goes on :( please give any advise for the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never faced this kind of issues before. However, your code is working fine for me (both of them). This is the output I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-9"?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      HU OIDB
    </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-9"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.oid.hacettepe.edu.tr/oidb.ico"/>
  </head>
...
</html>
```

Btw, did you notice there is a weird `İ` character in your output?

```
java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: İSO-8859-9
```

Based on the fact that I can run that and you can't I assume it might be some Operative System default value. And of course, it should be related to encoding.

You should try changing the JVM default charset. You can do that by using [JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#tooloptions) or via command line while running your application:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar YourApp.jar
```

Comment: Problem is solved I changed the system locale with Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH); thank you very much :)